# How to read variables of unknown width?

Tags: io, fortran

I think this is quite a basic question, but I can't seem to find the answer. I'm trying to read a file of the following form:

```
     1 filedir/i03j12_fort.4
    71 filedir/i04j01_fort.4
   224 filedir/i04j02_fort.4
```

I use the following command to get the initial integer, plus the 'i' and 'j' values from the filename (ldir is a string containing the length of filedir).

```
read(filenumber,'(i6,'//ldir//'x,i2,x,i2)') n,pix_i,pix_j
```

**the problem is that the amount of whitespace preceding the integer varies between files, so I have to manually change the width each time.** I have also tried not specifying a format, and reading the whole filename as a string, i.e.

```
read(filenumber,*) n, filename
```

but the filename returns weird characters (n works though).

**Is there any format statement that will read the integer up to the first whitespace it finds, to replace the 'i6' I have above?**

Thanks!

Comment: try `read(filenumber,'(i6,a)')n,filename`

Comment: Just deleted a comment from earlier saying it worked, as actually, I still have the problem with this that it assumes a certain width for the integer, but this can change from file to file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, here is my chosen solution, which relies on the fact that the string following the integer always starts with '/' (as it's a filepath):

```
! first determine how much whitespace is around the first integer
! and store this as string ln
 read(20, '(a)') filestring
 write(ln, "(I1)") INDEX(filestring, ' /')-1
 rewind(20)

! use ln to as the integer width
 read(filenumber,'(i'//ln//','//ldir//'x,i2,x,i2)') n,pix_i,pix_j
```

Answer (score 0):

No - you will need to process the file "manually".  Read it into a string, go looking for the first non-blank, then go looking for the next blank, then use internal io to read the relevant bits, etc.

As you have found, list directed io (using `*` as the format specifier) has some surprising features - one of them being that the slash character (`/`) in input means "stop reading here and leave remaining variables in the IO list as they were".  This doesn't work well when you have paths that contain slashes!

Just for fun...

```
PROGRAM read_some_things
  IMPLICIT NONE
  ! Some number bigger than most of the lines to be read.
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: line_buffer_size = 28
  ! Index of the start of the value of i in filename.
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: pos_i_in_filename = 10
  ! Index of the start of the value of j in filename.
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: pos_j_in_filename = 13
  CALL process_a_file
CONTAINS
  SUBROUTINE process_a_file
    INTEGER :: unit                       ! Unit number for IO.
    CHARACTER(:), ALLOCATABLE :: line     ! A line from the file.
    INTEGER :: iostat                     ! IOSTAT code.
    CHARACTER(256) :: iomsg               ! IOMSG to go with IOSTAT
    INTEGER :: n, i, j                    ! Numbers of interest.

    OPEN( NEWUNIT=unit, FILE='2015-01-09 read_some_things.txt', &
        ACTION='READ', STATUS='OLD', POSITION='REWIND' )
    DO
      CALL read_a_line(unit, line, iostat, iomsg)
      IF (IS_IOSTAT_END(iostat)) EXIT
      IF (iostat /= 0) THEN
        PRINT "('Error number ',I0,' reading file: ',A)",  &
            iostat, TRIM(iomsg)
        ERROR STOP ':('
      END IF

      ! What to do with an empty record?
      ! IF (LEN_TRIM(line) == 0) CALL Start_WW3

      CALL chop_a_line(line, n, i, j)
      PRINT "(2X,I0,1X,I0,1X,I0)", n, i, j
    END DO

    CLOSE(unit)
  END SUBROUTINE process_a_file

  ! Parse a line into numbers of interest.
  SUBROUTINE chop_a_line(line, n, i, j)
    CHARACTER(*), INTENT(IN) :: line      ! The line to chop.
    INTEGER, INTENT(OUT) :: n             ! Things we got...
    INTEGER, INTENT(OUT) :: i
    INTEGER, INTENT(OUT) :: j

    ! Various significnat character positions in the line.
    INTEGER :: first_non_blank_pos
    INTEGER :: next_blank_pos
    INTEGER :: before_filename_pos

    ! Buffer for assembling a format specification.
    CHARACTER(100) :: fmt

    ! Find start of first non-blank group.
    first_non_blank_pos = VERIFY(line, ' ')
    ! Tolerate its non-existence - this may be zero.

    ! Find start of the following blank group, starting from after 
    ! the beginning of the first non-blank group.
    next_blank_pos = SCAN(line(first_non_blank_pos+1:), ' ')
    ! It had better exist.  If it doesn't, confuse user.
    IF (next_blank_pos == 0) ERROR STOP 'I didn''t draw any blanks'
    next_blank_pos = next_blank_pos + first_non_blank_pos

    ! Find start of the second group of non-blanks, backup one.
    before_filename_pos = VERIFY(line(next_blank_pos:), ' ')
    ! It had better exist.  If it doesn't, annoy user.
    IF (before_filename_pos == 0) ERROR STOP 'Line in file with no file!'
    ! Note -2 to backup one and remember position before filename.
    before_filename_pos = before_filename_pos + next_blank_pos - 2

    ! This specifies:
    ! - read all prior to filename as integer, 
    ! - then skip to start of i, read I2, 
    ! - then skip to start of j, read I2.
    WRITE (fmt, "('(I',I0,',T',I0,',I2,T',I0,',I2)')")  &
        before_filename_pos,  &
        before_filename_pos + pos_i_in_filename,  &
        before_filename_pos + pos_j_in_filename

    READ (line, fmt) n, i, j
  END SUBROUTINE chop_a_line

  ! Read a record into a character variable.  Pretty common task...
  SUBROUTINE read_a_line(unit, line, iostat, iomsg)
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: unit           ! Unit to read from.
    CHARACTER(:), INTENT(OUT), ALLOCATABLE :: line  ! The record read.
    INTEGER, INTENT(OUT) :: iostat        ! +ve on error, -ve on eof.
    CHARACTER(*), INTENT(OUT) :: iomsg    ! IOMSG if iostat /= 0

    ! Buffer to read record fragment.
    CHARACTER(line_buffer_size) :: buffer
    INTEGER :: size           ! Amount read per read.

    line = ''
    DO
      ! Read a bit without always advancing to the next record.
      READ ( unit, "(A)", ADVANCE='NO', SIZE=size, IOSTAT=iostat,  &
          IOMSG=iomsg ) buffer
      IF (iostat > 0) RETURN        ! Bail on fail.
      ! Philosophical discussion about whether EOF is possible 
      ! and SIZE /= 0 goes here (consider STREAM access).
      line = line // buffer(:size)  ! Append what we got.
      ! Exit loop on end of file or end of record.
      IF (iostat < 0) EXIT
    END DO

    ! End of record is expected, not a relevant condition to return.
    IF (IS_IOSTAT_EOR(iostat)) iostat = 0
  END SUBROUTINE read_a_line
END PROGRAM read_some_things
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough response. I couldn't get your code to compile (I'm not much of a fortran expert though), but I think I found a simpler solution. Basically, I read the first line as a whole string, and use INDEX(string, ' /') to find the right width for the integer. I then rewind, and read all the lines as I was doing before, putting the appropriate integer width.