# Fortran 90: reading a generic string with enclosed some "/" characters

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

Hy everybody, I've found some problems in reading unformatted character strings in a simple file. When the first / is found, everything is missed after it.

This is the example of the text I would like to read: after the first 18 character blocks that are fixed (from #Mod to Flow[kW]), there is a list of chemical species' names, that are variables (in this case 5) within the program I'm writing.

```
 #Mod  ID Mod  Name       Type C.  #Coll    MF[kg/s]    Pres.[Pa]    Pres.[bar]    Temp.[K]    Temp.[C]    Ent[kJ/kg K]    Power[kW]    RPM[rad/s]    Heat Flow[kW]     METHANE     ETHANE      PROPANE    NITROGEN    H2O
```

I would like to skip, after some formal checks, the first 18 blocks, then read the chemical species. To do the former, I created a character array with dimension of 18, each with a length of 20.

```
character(20), dimension(18)       :: chapp
```

Then I would like to associate the 18 blocks to the character array

```
read(1,*) (chapp(i),i=1,18)
```

...but this is the result: from chapp(1) to chapp(7) are saved the right first 7 strings, but this is chapp(8)

```
chapp(8) = 'MF[kg               '
```

and from here on, everything is leaved blank!

How could I overcome this reading problem?

Comment: Probably not really a duplicate, but see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27849224/3157076 for why you see what you do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is due to your using list-directed input (the * as the format).  List-directed input is useful for quick and dirty input, but it has its limitations and quirks.

You stumbled across a quirk: A slash (`/`) in the input terminates assignment of values to the input list for the READ statement.  This is exactly the behavior that you described above.

This is not choice of the compiler writer, but is mandated by all relevant Fortran standards.

The solution is to use formatted input.  There are several options for this:

If you know that your labels will always be in the same columns, you can use a format string like `'(1X,A4,2X,A2,1X,A3,2X)'` (this is not complete) to read in the individual labels.  This is error-prone, and is also bad if the program that writes out the data changes format for some reason or other, or if the labes are edited by hand.

If you can control the program that writes the label, you  can use tab characters to separate the individual labels (and also, later, the labels). Read in the whole line, split it into tab-separated substrings using `INDEX` and read in the individual fields using an `(A)` format.  Don't use list-directed format, or you will get hit by the `/` quirk mentioned above. This has the advantage that your labels can also include spaces, and that the data can be imported from/to Excel rather easily. This is what I usually do in such cases.

Otherwise, you can read in the whole line and split on multiple spaces. A bit more complicated than splitting on single tab characters, but it may be the best option if you cannot control the data source. You cannot have labels containing spaces then.

Comment: I didn't know there could be some quirks reading with the unformatted mode, now I do! Thank you.