# Reading long pathname as string containing many forward slashes

Tags: fortran

I have a file `filenames.dat` that contains entries like this:

```
../Data/physionetdata/patient0006_s0022_lre/s0022lre.dat
../Data/physionetdata/patient0006_s0027_lre/s0027lre.dat
```

I want to read these entries using do loop one by one in a variable `filename`. So I tried this:

```
open(unit = 1, file = 'filenames.dat')

do i = 1, 10
    read(1,*)filename
enddo
```

However, Fortran stops at the first forward slash (`/`) which makes it impossible for me to store the file path in a variable `filename`.  How can I read the full path?

Comment: Perhaps not duplicates of the following, but they are useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28539857, http://stackoverflow.com/q/27846138.

Comment: `read(1,'(a)')filename`

Comment: @agentp : simple and elegant. Thanks a lot. Worked!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `newunit` specifier in your `open` statement to avoid nasty clashes. Manually setting connected file units is extremely error prone and difficult to maintain in larger programs.

To read from your file:

```
  integer :: u 
  open (newunit=u, file='filenames.dat', status='old') 

  do i = 1,10    
     read (u,'(a)') filenames 
  end do

  close (u)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The issue is all around use of list directed formatting and the special meaning of `/` in input.  The code in this answer has exactly the same issue.  Note also that NEWUNIT is a Fortran 2008 feature.  If the OP is using a compiler that does not support this feature, then use of NEWUNIT is simply not an option.

Comment: @Snehal Shekatkar `newunit` is supported by Cray, GNU (gfortran), IBM, Intel, NAG, and PGI.